# getting DNS name service error in google cloud complaining `krmanish.com’s server IP address could not be found.`

Tags: google-cloud-platform, googledns

I have deployed my application in google cloud, and exposed it to access it outside, but I can only access it using IP address and port number.

So, I purchased a domain in www.ionos.co.uk, and created a public zone in the google cloud. After adding the record set, I got the name server details, which I have added at www.ionos.co.uk.

Before the DNS setup, I was getting a different page, and once I set the name server in the domain site, I started getting an error `krmanish.com’s server IP address could not be found.`

I contacted ionos, they said the name server is configured correctly, and the request is going to that server. I don't know how to resolve the error.

Comment: PING krmanish.com (217.160.0.137): 56 data bytes
92 bytes from 217-160-0-137.elastic-ssl.ui-r.com (217.160.0.137): Destination Port Unreachable

Comment: Your name servers are not pointing to Google name servers: `ns-1and1.ui-dns.com`. `www.ionos.co.uk` points to IP `217.160.86.46`.

Comment: thanks @howie and @John Hanley, I had updated the NS in  `www.ionos.co.uk` but somehow it didn't updated correctly. I have contacted their customer service and they have updated it properly this time it seems. Now `ping krmanish.com` return 130.211.102.124. I should wait to 24 hr to see it reflecting properly.

Answer (score 0):

After you have set up your server, you should map your own domain name to your site. It seems like your domain name is not pointing to the IP address of the VM. If you want complete control of your own DNS system, you can use [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/) to serve as your domain name service (DNS) provider. If you need instructions that are specific to Cloud DNS, please see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart).

If you use separate providers for registration and DNS, make sure that your domain name registrar, has the correct name servers associated with your domain. Please see this [link] for steps to configure your Domain name.